# How can I use GetSection method by getting values and keys from appsettings.json' array parts?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core

How can I get `appsettings.json` data by using `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`? My JSON is below but this code doesn't work. Generally, my desire is getting an array or list. But I could not achieve it.

```
var someArray = configuration.GetSection("Test").GetChildren().Select(x => x).ToArray();
```

```js
"Test": [
  {
    "A": "101",
    "B": "6390"
  },
  {
    "A": "101",
    "B": "6391"
  },
  {
    "A": "101",
    "B": "6392"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply call [IConfiguration.AsEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.asenumerable) to convert it into an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` which you can then loop over. Note that the *key* is the configuration path, so for your example you would see keys like `Test:0:A` or `Test:2:B`.

```
foreach (var kv in Configuration.GetSection("Test").AsEnumerable())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
}
```

If you are within a configuration section, you can also use `AsEnumerable(makePathsRelative: true)` to flatten the keys and remove the section’s prefix.

Comment: Thank you - this is helpful. However... with a JSON object such as `{"parent": {"a": {children of a}, "b": {children of b}}}`, it's iterating over the children of a/b as well. How do I prevent that?

Comment: Configuration generally has no direct hierarchy, so enumerating it will give you all configuration items within the section. If you just want the direct childen, you can use [`IConfiguration.GetChildren()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration.getchildren) instead.

Comment: I edited your answer to show a solution to what I was wanting.. if that's not okay I'll post another answer

Comment: @ZachSmith That would be a solution for a different problem. There’s nothing special about using `GetChildren()` to get a *single* hierarchy level (and you don’t need to make it `AsEnumerable` since it’s already a collection). This question is about retrieving values for a deeper hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

you should cast it directly to your model.

```
services.Configure<AssetProviderConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AssetProvider"));
```

Then you can linq to your object.

I think you can directly do this, but not 100% sure.

```
var config = Configuration.GetSection("AssetProvider").Get<AssetProviderC‌​onfig>();
```

give it a shot!

Comment: It would be `var config = Configuration.GetSection("AssetProvider").Get<AssetProviderConfig>();`

Comment: `GetSection` returns an `IConfiguration` which you cannot cast into a different type. You would have to *bind* it using the configuration binder.

Comment: @ChrisPratt and poke, I was affraid that I was wrong ;) Just out of my head eh.. thnx for the update! I edit the answer!